# Format caption in figure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I have a question which concerns text formatting in captions and also in sections. For example when I type:

```
\begin{figure}
something

\caption{this is some caption text and it probably may be quite long.}
\end{figure}
```

Then result is:

```
something

this is some caption text and it pro-    
bably may be quite long.
```

The word 'probably' is divided and text in new line is aligned to left. I would like to stop word division and align entire text to center. I know that I can use mbox, but it's somehow irritating to write it all the time, so maybe some global setting would be nicer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'and also in sections' in your first sentence? You only mention figure caption afterwards.

Comment: I mean how to stop word division also in sections.

Comment: If with 'sections' you mean `\section' titles then this requires a completely different solution and should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

load package `caption` with

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```